# Strong type checking for non existent file declared in a function parameter

Tags: powershell

I am writing a PowerShell function that carries out some operation on a file, the path to the file is passed to the function as a parameter. I'm a fan of strong typing and parameter validation so instead of just passing the file path as a `System.String` I've defined the parameter like so:

```
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
[ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
[System.Management.Automation.PathInfo]$PathInfo
```

Normally I would use `Resolve-Path` in the calling code to get an object of type `System.Management.Automation.PathInfo` that I could pass to this parameter however in this case it is legitimate for the file to not yet exist and hence `Resolve-Path` would throw an error.

Is it possible to instantiate an instance of `System.Management.Automation.PathInfo` for a none-existent file? If so, how? If not, do you have a suggestion for how I might pass a non-existent file path to a function and still have strong type checking.

Comment: What about `FileInfo`? A `FileInfo` instance can point to a non-existent directory / file (`$pathInfo = New-Object IO.FileInfo C:\non-existent.txt`)

Comment: DOH! Too easy. Thank you sir.

Comment: @jamiet you can also check whether the file exists or not, directly on the `FileInfo` object: `([System.IO.FileInfo]"C:\nonexist.ext").Exists`

Comment: Nice, thank you @MathiasR.Jessen

Answer (score 2):

Although using the `[System.IO.FileInfo]` type would probably be the neatest solution in this case (doing something to a *file*), you might run into problems if you're given a path to a *folder*, since `.Exists` returns **False** in such cases. You'd want to use `[System.IO.DirectoryInfo]` instead...

Thinking a bit more generally you could use a validation script, esp. one that calls some sort of testing function, for example the following should allow parameters that are either `$null` or a valid `[System.Management.Automation.PathInfo]` type.

```
function Test-Parameter {
  param($PathInfo)

  if([System.String]::IsNullOrEmpty($PathInfo)) {
    return $true

  } elseif($PathInfo -is [System.Management.Automation.PathInfo]) {
    return $true

  } else {
    return $false
  }
}
```

And then you use this a `[ValidateScript({...})]` check your parameter meets those (arbitrary) conditions:

```
function Do-Something {
  param(
    [Parameter()]
      [ValidateScript({Test-Parameter $_})]
      $PathInfo
  )

  ....
}
```